# Adding object when nested in Javascript with ES6

Tags: javascript, object, nested, javascript-objects, assign

I am trying to add an object, but it seems like it is overwriting instead of being added.

I have an initial object:

```js
const config = {
    person: 'Bob',
    employer: 'yahoo',
}
```

I'm making a new object elsewhere like so:

```js
const newConfig = {
        ...config,
        customText: { [myVar]: messageText },
        [myVar]: selectedItem,
      };
```

myVar can be either `message` or `note` that gets sent to Bob.

First, you write a `message` to Bob, so newConfig looks like this:

```js
const config = {
    person: 'Bob',
    employer: 'yahoo',
    customText: { message: 'hi bob!' }
}
```

But then later I add a note, and I want the result to be:

```js
const config = {
    person: 'Bob',
    employer: 'yahoo',
    customText: { message: 'hi bob!', note: 'please leave a message for Bob' }
}
```

Instead, it seems like my object is being overwritten.

```js
const config = {
    person: 'Bob',
    employer: 'yahoo',
    customText: { note: 'please leave a message for Bob' }
}
```

I've tried to use Object.assign, but I end up in a similar conundrum.

```
const customText = Object.assign({}, newConfig.customText, {[myVar]: messageText});
```

I've also tried doing something with the object assignation:

```js
const newConfig = {
        ...config,
        customText[myVar]: messageText,
        [myVar]: selectedItem,
      };
```

But I'm getting an `Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","`

How can I add the object without overwriting it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to spread customText too, else it replaces the customText with new property everytime

```
const newConfig = {
        ...config,
        customText: {...config.customText, [myVar]: messageText },
        [myVar]: selectedItem,
};
```

Comment: Thank you! So this is passing in the old value and the new value and both assigning to customText. Got it!